# Can I upgrade Laptop CPU

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have an old Dell Inspiron 15Z. It has a 3rd gen intel core i7 processor. For various reasons ranging from cost, through waste disposal concerns and attachment, I do not want to get a new laptop computer. Is it possible to upgrade this CPU to the latest 8th gen CPUs?

Comment: Ultrabooks are typically an all-in-one board so no, you can't replace just the CPU.

Comment: More than likely not, since the CPU is probably soldered to the motherboard. Laptops are tricky when it comes to upgrades. Basically the RAM and disk drives are something you can upgrade. When it comes to a CPU upgrade in a laptop, it's usually a no.

Comment: “ Is it possible to upgrade this CPU to the latest 8th gen CPUs?” This is **impossible** the 3rd generation Core processors used an entirely different socket then a 8th generation. So what you want isn’t possible.

Comment: My Dell Inspiron 1545, a very similar laptop, has a removeable CPU and...... GPU!!!

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Ivy Bridge micro-architecture (3rd generation mobile) works on socket Socket G2
**BGA-1023** while the Kaby Lake micro-architecture (7th/8th generation mobile) works on **BGA 1440** so they are **physically incompatible**.

In fact, Intel managed to have 10 different sockets for 7 generations of CPUs (G1, 1288, G2, 1023, 1224, G3, 1364, 1168, 1536, 1440).